# My Particles Aren't Appending At My Player X and Y

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to append my particles at my player1 and player2, x and y whenever the ball collides with them but it doesn't seem like it's appearing at its x and y it's just appearing at 1 position [VIDEO](https://gyazo.com/f8a230a226a8d81d320616fba48763a3)

```
        if ball1.rect.colliderect(player1.rect):
            for x in range(50):
                particles.append(particle(player1.x,player1.y)) # this suppose to make the particles append at player 1 x and y when ball collides with them
            
            
        if ball1.rect.colliderect(player2.rect):
            for x in range(50):
                particles.append(particle(player2.x,player2.y)) # this suppose to make the particles append at player 2 x and y when ball collides with them
```

my particle class

```
    class particle:
        def __init__(self,x,y):
            self.x = x
            self.y = y
            self.x_vel = random.randrange(-10,13)*1
            self.y_vel = random.randrange(-10,-1)*1
            self.lifetime = 0
        def draw(self,window):
            self.lifetime += 1
            if self.lifetime <30:
                self.x -= self.x_vel
                self.y -= self.y_vel
                pygame.draw.circle(window,(255,255,255),(self.x,self.y),10)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your particles are always occurring at the start position of the Player.
Looking at your [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62650149/having-trouble-with-particles-pygame), your Player initially sets it `.x` and `.y`, but only updates these in `.draw()`.  But! The `Player` class has *two* definitions of `Player.draw()`, and the second one (which will "overwrite" the first), does *not* update the `x` and `y` position.

So when the `Particle` objects are created at the player `x,y`, it's the original starting point of the player, not the current point.

Probably, you just need to create the particles with updated `Player.rect` co-ordinates:

```
x, y = player1.rect.center
particles.append( particle( x, y ) )
```

But maybe you want to create these effects where the ball hits the Player's bat.  This would be the ball position at the point of collision (maybe with a small offset).

```
    if ball1.rect.colliderect( collision2.rect ):
        x, y = ball1.rect.center
        particles.append( particle( x, y ) )
```

Comment: Thanks  that will do